# Case folding variation to variable so input matches one of assigned variables

Tags: python, string, case-folding

Creating a guess a word game and secret_word can be in any variation but how would I write different variation of secret_word is recognized by the program?

In this case, secret word is "Korea", how am I able to unify any variation or do I have to insert every different kind of variation?

```py
secret_word = {"korea", "kOrea", "KoRea", "KoReA", "KOrea", "KORea", "Korea", "KOREA"}
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Guess a word: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
print("Maybe Next time! You are out of guesses")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short**: case insensitive checking is a much harder problem than what it appears to be at first sight. The [**`str.casefold()`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is supposed to produce a string for such comparisons.

You check if the `.casefold()` of the entered string is the same as the `.casefold()` of the string to guess, like:

```
secret_word = 'korea'
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('Guess a word')
    if guess.casefold() == secret_word.casefold():
        break
    else:
        guess_count += 1

if guess_count < guess_limit:
    print('You win')
else:
    print('You lose')
```

The `.casefold()` is supposed, by the [*Unicode standard*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#G33992) to produce a string that can be compared for *case-insensitive* comparisons. For example in German, the [*eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) maps in uppercase to:

```
>>> 'ß'.lower()
'ß'
>>> 'ß'.upper()
'SS'
>>> 'SS'.lower()
'ss'
>>> 'ß'.lower() == 'SS'.lower()
False
```

whereas the `.casefold()` will return `ss`:

```
>>> 'ß'.casefold()
'ss'
>>> 'ss'.casefold()
'ss'
>>> 'ß'.casefold() == 'SS'.casefold()
True
```

A case-insensitive comparison turns out to be a hard problem, since certain characters have no upper/lowercase equivalent, etc.

Comment: Did you forget guess = ""? or is it not required?  I see guess = input('Guess a word')

Comment: @JMin: no that is not required, since we set it in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep the secret in lower (or upper) case, and then convert the guess to that case:

```
secret_word = 'korea'

while guess.lower() != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    # loop's body...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `guess.lower()` which converts every variation of `guess` into lowercase.
So you only have to give the lowercase variation.

> lower(self, /)
>   Return a copy of the string converted to lowercase.
>   -- *help(str.lower)*

```py
secret_word = "korea"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess.lower() != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Guess a word: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Maybe Next time! You are out of guesses")
else:
    print("You win!")
```